# Using decorator design pattern to create a doubly linked list by decorating a singly linked list

Tags: c++, design-patterns, decorator, singly-linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I am quite a newbie when it comes to design patterns so am having a hard time grasping the concept of the decorator design pattern. Is it possible to decorate a singly linked list class to a doubly linked list class which inherits from it? I would like to decorate the following class:

ListAsSLL.h:

```
#ifndef LISTASSLL_H
#define LISTASSLL_H

class ListAsSLL
{
protected:
    struct node{
        int i;
        struct node* next;
    };
    node* head;
    node* tail;
    int listSize;

public:
    ListAsSLL();
    virtual void addToBeginning(int obj);
    virtual void addAtPos(int obj, int i);
    virtual void addToEnd(int obj);
    virtual void del(int i);
    virtual void overwrite(int obj, int i);
    virtual void grow();
    virtual void shrink();
};

#endif //LISTASSLL_H
```

Giving the doubly linked list class the same functionality with the added feature of having a struct with a pointer to the previous node.

Hopefully someone can shed some light on how to do this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is interface for double linked list you need to implement?

Comment: @Slava The exact same interface as for ListAsSLL

Comment: Then you do not understand what decorator pattern is used for. It is used when you have requirement for one interface and you have another. So you use a decorator to provide required interface. What you are trying to do completely unrelated to decorator pattern.

Comment: @Slava That's why I'm so confused. I got given this in an assignment. They said that ListAsDLL is implemented by decorating ListAsSLL. I can't see at all how ListAsSLL is being decorated.

Comment: Just inherit `ListAsDLL` from `ListAsSLL` and inherit `struct node` there as well( add anothed pointer `prev`). Then reimplement all virtual methods accordingly (you should call parent method and then modify `prev` in derived method so it points to previous element).

Comment: I am forced to have ListAsDLL inherit from ListAsSLL which is really stupid. That why I am asking if it is possible to decorate ListAsSLL to have the prev attribute in the struct node..?

Comment: It depends on how `ListAsSLL` methods are implemented

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124325/discussion-between-keagansed-and-slava).

Comment: I cannot chat, sorry.

Comment: Ok well how does it depend on the way they're implemented? How would I have to implement them to be able to do that. That is my question

Comment: You need to inherit from `ListAsSLL::node`, intercept creation of `ListAsSLL::node` in base class and create inherited one. How to do that depends on `ListAsSLL` implementation.

Comment: Could you show me how to do this in answer form?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how it can be implemented. I added another virtual method `createNode` and show possible implementation of `addToBeginning()`.

```
class ListAsSLL
{
protected:
    struct node{
        int i;
        struct node* next;
    };
    node* head;
    node* tail;
    int listSize;

    virtual node *createNode() { return new node; }
public:
    virtual void addToBeginning(int obj) 
    {
       node *node = createNode();
       node->i = obj;
       node->next = head;
       if( !head ) tail = node;
       head = node;
       ++listsize;
    }
    ...
};

class ListAsDLL
{
protected:
    struct dnode : node{
        node* prev;
    };

    virtual node *createNode() { return new dnode; }
public:
    virtual void addToBeginning(int obj) 
    {
       node *prevHead = head;
       ListAsSLL::addToBeginning( obj );
       static_cast<dnode *>( head )->prev = prevHead;
    }
    ...
};
```

Code was not tested, though may have logic errors, as was written to show general idea.